# Firma Digital en XML DIAN Colombia

Tags: php, xml, webservice, firma-digital

Estoy en la realización de la firma digital para la factura electrónica en Colombia y he estado haciendo las validaciones correspondientes y me pasa que he validado el archivo XML en página tales como:

https://tools.chilkat.io/xmlDsigVerify.cshtml#generatedCode
https://www.aleksey.com/cgi-bin/xmldsigverify 
 Y también con este programa:
XML ValidatorBuddy

Tanto en las dos primeros enlaces que son validadores online como en el último  me arroja que el archivo XML la firma digital está bien pero cuando lo envío a la DIAN me dice que la firma está revocada o hay inconsistencias,  les agradecería que me digan que es lo que estoy haciendo mal muchas gracias

Dejo la estructura del elemento ds:Signature con las referencias y los digest generados...Muchas gracias

```
        <ext:UBLExtension>
  <ext:ExtensionContent><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" xmlns:xades141="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#" Id="xmldsig-3d4fab77-1cd1-45c1-b83e-8fe99b596566"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/><ds:Reference Id="xmldsig-3d4fab77-1cd1-45c1-b83e-8fe99b596566-ref0" URI=""><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><ds:DigestValue>dgsHIZx49492MKkwson1wwEZWaBCc78kh/RIvd/W6gw=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference><ds:Reference URI="#xmldsig-3d4fab77-1cd1-45c1-b83e-8fe99b596566-KeyInfo">
      <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
      <ds:DigestValue>RAAw1KtgQbiPa7BrP0csKF3yBt1oW2H5uHZhHJHEh6M=</ds:DigestValue>
    </ds:Reference><ds:Reference Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties" URI="#xmldsig-3d4fab77-1cd1-45c1-b83e-8fe99b596566-SignedProperties">
      <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
      <ds:DigestValue>hQ3MrjVqLU4RBz814sstqizV/GkuXMJRdZPi+2c56Sg=</ds:DigestValue>
    </ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue Id="xmldsig-3d4fab77-1cd1-45c1-b83e-8fe99b596566-sigvalue">A6pDX4mW2wUf0xUy6XGSX7cA+YqI3GhDERmGygSOijRse4aToq94d9SZG3fRXMWweFpYDWwdTGvqFlZBp2Q0Wqawfz88cWKvOykAZ6NPcNe6fB4wf0qqoRbb7Wu4auI19kS5qOEZp7biCNa4Q0iJP663HpMMT5Crq/iJi7OTpORtNIUbe6JBwEIicS5rasF965b0FYHPt1uYTaSeNOjo/ETmfV8wb6kPMNjk6id+KV6YByQCseMZzhQ66Fp7exZVxJG5JCb2RtqFOHRmgf3D0eUtJsJb384xnPLTwT603e/qVWpW6ykYbkpmS2stD7ASSwLO8wSeayIKe2AzV4T/HA==</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo Id="xmldsig-3d4fab77-1cd1-45c1-b83e-8fe99b596566-KeyInfo"><ds:X509Data>
        <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
    </ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo><ds:Object><xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" xmlns:xades141="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#" Target="#xmldsig-3d4fab77-1cd1-45c1-b83e-8fe99b596566"><xades:SignedProperties Id="xmldsig-3d4fab77-1cd1-45c1-b83e-8fe99b596566-SignedProperties">
            <xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
              <xades:SigningTime>2018-11-09T07:45:25-05:00</xades:SigningTime>    
              <xades:SigningCertificate>
                <xades:Cert>
                  <xades:CertDigest>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                    <ds:DigestValue>sF4EOB2o1T+RdB3/Tj/cc5FF3ifgaXNlnF5FtE4E2bI=</ds:DigestValue>
                  </xades:CertDigest>
                  <xades:IssuerSerial>
                    <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=AC SUB CERTICAMARA,C=CO,L=BOGOTA,O=CERTICAMARA S.A,NIT=NIT 830084433-7,ST=DISTRITO CAPITAL,STREET=www.certicamara.com</ds:X509IssuerName>
                    <ds:X509SerialNumber>104754875592334984367834349340962153552</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                  </xades:IssuerSerial>
                </xades:Cert>
              </xades:SigningCertificate>
              <xades:SignaturePolicyIdentifier>
                <xades:SignaturePolicyId>
                  <xades:SigPolicyId>
                    <xades:Identifier>https://facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co/politicadefirma/v2/politicadefirmav2.pdf</xades:Identifier>
        <xades:Description>Politica de firma para facturas electronicas de la Republica de Colombia</xades:Description>
                  </xades:SigPolicyId>
                  <xades:SigPolicyHash>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                    <ds:DigestValue>dMoMvtcG5aIzgYo0tIsSQeVJBDnUnfSOfBpxXrmor0Y=</ds:DigestValue>
                  </xades:SigPolicyHash>
                </xades:SignaturePolicyId>
              </xades:SignaturePolicyIdentifier>  
              <xades:SignerRole>
                <xades:ClaimedRoles>
                  <xades:ClaimedRole>supplier</xades:ClaimedRole>
                </xades:ClaimedRoles>
              </xades:SignerRole>
            </xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
          </xades:SignedProperties></xades:QualifyingProperties></ds:Object></ds:Signature></ext:ExtensionContent>
</ext:UBLExtension>
```

Comment: Hola Jairo, podrías orientarme un poco respecto a la facturación electrónica... veo que tienes tu servicio en PHP, como para darme un rumbo.

Comment: Hola Jairo me interesaria ponerme en contacto contigo porque estoy en el mismo proceso, llevo mas avance realizado pero tengo algunas dudas que igual podriamos apoyarnos para resolverlas y darle solucion.